# Why are my MapView's zoom limits not working?

Tags: expo, react-native-maps

I am trying to restrict the max zoom "out" for an application I am making. The issue is that, even though I set pretty limited zoom restrictions, the user can still zoom in and out as far as they want. I'm relatively new to Expo applications, so it might be something I just don't understand about the `react-native-maps` library.

Here is how my map's `render()` method looks:

```
render() {

        return (
            <MapView
                style={styles.mapStyle}
                region={this.state.region}
                provider="google"
                zoomEnabled={false}
                minZoomLevel={18}
                maxZoomLevel={20}
                showsMyLocationButton={true}
                showsUserLocation={true}
            />
        )
    }
```

I have logic in place to center the map on the user's location (not shown - that's handled in `componentDidMount()`), but the zoom restrictions here don't seem to have an effect beyond the initial rendering of the map. Once the user zooms out, the sky is the limit - they can zoom out to see the whole world, if they wanted to. That's not very useful for my app, so I'd like to get these restrictions working (or at least a better understanding of how this works). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After about 6 more minutes of digging (/facepalm), I found out where I was messing up. The "issue" was that I did not understand how these Zoom values worked. It's a bit odd, but in general:

- **The lower the zoom value, the FARTHER OUT it is from the map (e.g., low zoom values === large area of map is shown)**

  - This was a bit counter intuitive to me; I kept getting tripped up thinking that `0` was the "closest" level zoom, but it's actually the farthest

### What I accomplished with this fix

This fix enabled me to make the map prevent the user from zooming out past the "farthest out" zoom level; in my case, I am using a `minZoomLevel` of `10`, which is about the area of a large city and the surrounding areas. I am using a `maxZoomLevel` of `20`, which is the "closest possible" zoom level.

Additionally, I needed to remove `zoomEnabled={false}` - this was a holdover from me poking around in my code earlier - this setting PREVENTS ALL ZOOM INTERACTIONS (and it also tripped me up until I remembered to remove it).

Hope this helps others!